# Xubuntu - Suspend on Lock

Tags: xubuntu, suspend, power-management

After nearly a decade, I've decided to give XFCE a try with Xubuntu 21.10 on the ever-reliable ThinkPad X1. Just about everything has been remarkably painless to configure, but I cannot for the life of me get the system to suspend when the lock screen is active. Instead, the system remains active all night, though the screen is off. I wonder if I'm missing something.

I have configured the system to use a screensaver after 15 minutes of inactivity. Pressing <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to lock the screen (as one does) will also activate the screensaver. Everything is good.

The power manager is set to put the system to sleep after 20 minutes of inactivity for both battery and when plugged in.

[image: Screensaver & Power Preferences]

If I leave the system alone for 15 minutes, the screensaver kicks in just fine. If I lock the screen, the screensaver kicks in just fine. If I leave the system for 25 minutes, the screen is still active. If I leave the system for 35+ minutes (15 for the screensaver and 20 for the power manager?) then the screen is off, but the system is still running.

There is no priority process running in the background. The system is quite idle aside from NextCloud Sync and whatever Javascript might be running in a browser.

What combination of settings do I need to have the system suspend after a set number of minutes idle?

**Hardware:**

Lenovo ThinkPad X1 Carbon
CPU: Intel Core i5-7200U
RAM: 16GB

**OS:**

Xubuntu 21.10
Kernel: 5.13.0-22-generic